# ООП. В чем смысл создания объектов на основе родительских классов

Tags: java, ооп

Я изучаю Java и столкнулся с таким способом создания объекта:

***РодительскийКласс** объект = new **ДочернийКласс***.

Я все-таки не пойму в чем смысл создания объектов на основе родительских классов?
Например, если у меня есть родительский класс "Car" и дочерний класс "Jeep extends Car"
Зачем мне делать **Car jeep = new Jeep()**, если этот мой объект jeep будет урезанным, по сравнению с **Jeep jeep = new Jeep()**.

Comment: Чтобы передать родительский функционал дочернему классу. Например, если какой-то метод у родителя меняется, то у дочернего класса соответственно тоже.

Comment: Но, насколько я понимаю, если class Jeep extends Car, то Jeep jeep = new Jeep() все-равно будет видеть все методы класса Car

Answer (score 0):

В таком использовании конечно смысла не много. Вот другой пример:

```java
Car car;
if (bad_road) 
   car = new Jeep();
else if (very_bad_road)
   car = new Tank();
else
   car = new Coupe();
```

Теперь есть `car` типа `Car` и можно вызывать его методы.

Comment: Спасибо, очень наглядно. Но если для объекта класса Car car = new Jeep(); мне нужно будет задействовать например метод "полный привод" - car.wheelDrive(), который есть только у класса Jeep?

Comment: Вообще говоря, в этом случае car.wheelDrive() конечно не вызвать. И как правило это и не надо. Если у вас есть код, который должен например управлять машиной, ему должно быть все равно что у него за машина, главное что есть методы "run()", "brake()".
Но если очень надо - то всегда можно проверить что переданный `car` это `Jeep` с помощью оператора `instanceof`, привести его к этому типу и вызвать конкретный  метод.
Но более корректно такую логику реализовывать через интерфейсы

Comment: Простите, если мой вопрос покажется глупым, я немного запутался. Насколько я понимаю я создаю объект один раз и взаимодействую с ним с помощью разных методов. А если я сделаю объекту `car` приведение к типу `Jeep` (вот так: `Jeep jeep2 = (Jeep)jeep;`), то это будет уже совсем другой объект, который к первому `jeep` не имеет никакого отношения. Т.е. получается что, если у меня в программе будут методы, которым нужно вызывать метод `wheelDrive()` и которым не нужно, то мне прийдется создавать разные объекты для каждого из этих методов.

Comment: Нет, это будет тот же объект. НО приведение сработает только если этот объект действительно Jeep. Иначе будет ошибка во время выполнения программы.

Comment: Да, проверил - действительно так, `Car jeep = new Jeep()`  и `Jeep jeep2 = (Jeep)jeep` - это один и тот-же объект, но теперь у меня в программе будет просто две копии одного объекта. Т.е. `jeep2` никак не замещает собой `jeep`. А конструкция приведения типа `Jeep jeep = (Jeep)jeep` не работает.

Comment: Это не две копии объекта - это один и тот же объект под разными именами.

Comment: Теперь понятно, спасибо. :)